# Prove that |Λ/e| = |Λ|-|P|

Tags: category-theory, modules, projective-module, algebras, representation-of-algebras

Let Λ be a ﬁnite dimensional basic algebra over an algebraically closed ﬁeld k. Let P be a finitely generated left Λ module and e an idempotent of Λ such that addP = addΛe.  we denote by addP (respectively, addΛe) the category of all direct summands of finite direct sums of copies of P(respectively, Λe). How can I prove that |Λ/e| = |Λ|-|P|,  where |X| denotes the number of nonisomorphic indecomposable direct summands of X?